# Plotly: Problem with plotly express add_vrect to figure

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly express facet_row plot with three subplots that works nicely. I would like to add a box to all the the rows that colours a specific region of the plot and adds a text. The add_vrect should do the job, but I struggle to get it to work.

https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/
https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/

Code that works below

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

ftir_data_facet = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\mch047\Box Sync\PhD project Mikkel C\OneDrive - UiT Office 365\Mikkel_Christensen\Bioinformatics\Paper 1\Figure 2 Plate screen panel\Full_FTIR_dataset\Paper1_Figure2_FTIR_tidy_faceformat_071120.csv", sep=";")
#ftir_data_facet

figure2_facet = px.scatter(ftir_data_facet, x="Wavenumbers (1/cm)", y="Absorbance", color="Strain", facet_row="Plate")

figure2_facet.update_xaxes(title_text="Wavenumbers (1/cm)", range=[4000, 1000], showgrid=False)
fig.show()
```

I have tried to add:

```
figure2_facet.add_vrect(x0="1750", x1="1700", row=All, 
             annotation_text="Carbonyl region", annotation_position="top left",
             fillcolor="green", opacity=0.25, line_width=0)
```

I get:

"AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_vrect'"

Can anybody help or explain why it does not work..?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a version problem. `add_vrect()` seems to have been introduced as a [new functinality](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases) along with quite a few others in version `4.12.0` as of 23.10.2020:

> #### Added
>
> Shapes that reference the plot axes in one dimension and the data in another dimension can
> be added with the new add_hline, `add_vline`, `add_hrect`, `add_vrect`
> functions, which also support the `row="all"` and `col="all"` arguments.
> (#2840) The `add_trace`, `add_shape`, `add_annotation`, `add_layout_image`,
> `add_hline`, `add_vline`, `add_hrect`, `add_vrect` functions accept an
> argument exclude_empty_subplots which if True, only adds the object to
> subplots already containing traces or layout objects. This is useful
> in conjunction with the `row="all"` and `col="all"` arguments.

So my initial suggestion would be to update plotly and try again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I have now updated plotly, but I keep getting the same error, even after several restarts of the computer.

Comment: but it seems more of a local problem with Anaconda and updating on my machine. Will see if I get it fixed or have to re-install to test if it will work.

Comment: @MikkelC How did it all work out for you in the end?

Comment: it worked out in the end - sent emails to my IT department complaining about not having admin rigths on my work pc user necessary for receiving emails etc, and uninstalled and re-installed Anaconda and the necessary packages. The latter option was 1 week faster and without grumpy complaints about Anaconda not updating for all users when I update with the admin account. So I guess I will encounter this problem again since our IT department do not believe our local user should have Admin rigths... Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the rigth direction :-)